# Should I pass a class to my (React) component, and keep my state in that component

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm creating an application that receives a JSON object I need to visualise to an editor to edit this JSON and POST back. I transform the JSON to classes as soon as I receive the code. The classes have methods to edit the items.

At this moment I'm using React, which is new for me, to visualise the JSON as an editor. I always pass the classes I create to the components and use methods on those classes to update the state. The classes are my single source of truth for the data.

**I wonder if this is a good approach in the world of frontend component based development.**

What I do in the example of a todoList:

I receive a JSON object with a todolist name and an array of todos which I convert to a class:

```
const json = {
  "title": "My todolist",
  "items": [
    {"title": "todo 1", done: false}
  ]
}
```

becomes

````
class TodoList {
  constructor(name, items) {
    this.name = name;
    this.items = items.map(item => return new TodoItem(item) )
  }
}

class TodoItem {
  constructor(title, done) {
    this.title = title;
    this.done = done;
  }

  markDone() {
    this.done = true;
  }
}

```

Now when I print my todoitem + button to mark it done I do something like this:

```
export function TodoItem(props) {
  const todoItem = props.todoItem; // this is the TodoItem class 

  const [item2, setItem] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setItem(todoItem);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item2.title}, done: {item2.done ? 'true' : 'false'}</h1>
      <button onClick={(e) => { 
          e.preventDefault();
          item2.markDone();
          setItem({...item2});
        }}>Mark as done</button>
    </div>
  );
}

```

Full example here: https://playcode.io/1165575

The data in the class gets updated and on a later moment I can convert the classes back to JSON and send it back.

**I wonder if this is a good approach in the world of frontend component based development.**
````

Answer (score 0):

You should only pass to TodoItem the necessary props to render + a callback to update the state. Let me show you:

```js
const TodoList = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    return(
        {items.map((item, index) => (
            <TodoItem 
                title={item.title}
                done={item.done}
                onChange={newValue => {
                    let newItems = items;
                    newItems[index].done = newValue;

                    setItems(newItems);
                }}
            />
        ))}
    );
};

const TodoItem = ({ title, done, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title}, done: {done}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => {
                onChange(!done);
            }}>Mark as {done? 'undone' : 'done'}</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```